# Is there a length limit for variable names in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have researched standards of Haskell. They state that there is no length limit for a variable's name. How is this implemented in GHC? Is there a length limit for variable names?

Comment: For history buffs, there was a bug in GHC were programs were slower when module names were > 10 characters. [Enjoy](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.glasgow.user/16037).

Comment: There's always a limit set by the available memory.  Specific platforms may also have a limit on the lengths of identifiers in generated object code (which I don't think ghc works around).

Comment: Why do you assume GHC uses an upper limit?

Comment: I know that some language doesn't limit length of variable names in its specification. When it comes to implementation there is a limit.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez To be fair I think asking "Is there one?" doesn't assume that there is one. =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no hard length limit in the GHC implementation.

Comment: There does appear to be a soft limit of 1 character in most Haskell developers though...

Comment: @RichardHuxton Indeed, a,b,c,i,j,k,n,x,y,xs,ys is the complete vocabulary of a true Haskell programmer, where a,b and c are only needed for writng types.